# Matlab: fmincon(@...)

Tags: matlab, optimization

following some researches on [mathworks.com](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) I am currently executing the following command:

```
options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','sqp','Display','off');    
params = fmincon(@(par) test_llk(data,par), par0,[0 0 0 0 0 1 1],1,...
[],[],[0 -1 0 -inf],[2 1 inf inf],[],options);
```

and wonder if there is a way of updating

**1**- *the above constraint* from:

```
par(6) + par(7) <=1 ;
```

to:

```
par(6) + par(7) < 1  ;
```

**2**- from the *lower bound*

```
lb=[0 -1 0 -inf];
```

getting a way of setting

```
lb(3) > 0
```

instead of being currently set to:

```
lb(3) >= 0
```

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, there is currently no way to change the inequality constraints to be strictly less or greater than instead.  One thing I've seen people do is **add/subtract** a small constant to the constraint.  For example, `par(6) + par(7) <= 1` would be come `par(6) + par(7) < 1 - tol`, where `tol` is a very small number... perhaps `eps`.  Similarly, `lb(3) >= 0` would become `lb(3) >= eps`.  Check out [`eps`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) for more details.

Comment: A stricly less constraint doesn't really make sense, because an infinitesimal amount changes strictly less into less-or-equal. Adding a small but finite constant is the way to go.

Comment: Just think about this: Find the value x that maximizes f(x) = x under the constraint x < 1. What is the answer?

Comment: @rayryeng: Thanks. `eps` should do the 'trick'.

Comment: @A.Donda: I will favor the `eps` solution, but thanks for the Thought.

Comment: @owner, well yes, you should use a small but finite constant like `eps`. I just added a hint as to why a strictly less constraint doesn't make sense.